# Code-generation using Excel: Generate HTML from within Excel

Tags: html, excel, code-generation, vba

**Problem:**

I have a user who would like to generate an HTML page directly from Excel (without doing file-save as) but instead click a button and have the current worksheet (or a modified variant thereof) contents just 'pop-up' inside a script-generated HTML page. The rationale is that the Excel content could be used to navigate to different web pages automatically, based on the values entered in the cells by the user.

**Question:**

1) Has anyone done this kind of thing using Excel, and are there any security implications, above and beyond just the ordinary considerations that go with having macros enabled in Excel.

2) Has anyone done this using an alternate methodology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not write a VBA macro that does the "Save As" operation to save the file in HTML format?

You don't even have to record the macro, you could probably record it using the macro recorder.

1. Start macro recorder
2. Save As - HTML format
3. Stop macro recorder
4. Assign macro to a button

Comment: Unless you want all the additional markup Excel adds to the file using this method, you can alternatively build a simple VBA macro that scans the current selection and outputs simple HTML code.

Comment: Greetings Joel, it sounds convoluted, but the rationale is to create an HTML page that a novice-level user can *interact with* ... and simply press a button on the HTML page, which in turn would submit content to a destination website via HTTP POST.

In other words, the goal is to find a *brain dead simple* way to get content out of Excel and up to a web server *without* requiring the specific user to know how to even save a file in Excel, but just click two buttons.